# Regular expression to split by space but ignore double-quotes string

Tags: php, regex

I know `/[\s]+/'` splits a string by spaces. I am trying to expand this to ignore any spaces within double quotes. So I want `Hello World` to be split, but not `"Hello World"`

`preg_split('/[\s]+/', $string)` is the expression I am using in PHP.

Comment: how should this `'hello "again we met" and here "I am" '` be splitted?

Comment: I am only interested in ignoring double quoted strings.

Comment: @chris85 that's exactly what I needed. Thanks.

Comment: I am reopening this because @chris85 answer is good and from the dup question link, nobody mentions this easy way to do it (answer was match all) and his answer can be used in _preg_split()_ I encourage chris85 to post his comment as an answer.

Comment: @sln Thanks. I've moved comment to an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the PCRE verbs `(*SKIP)(*FAIL)` to tell the regex to skip specific parts of an expression. So:

```
".*?"(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|\s+
```

will skip double quoted strings. Here's a regex101 demo:

https://regex101.com/r/eBP67C/1/

You can read more about this here, http://www.rexegg.com/regex-best-trick.html#pcrevariation.